# .Net\AJAX Listbox and updatepanel problem

Tags: .net, ajax, listbox

I have a listbox(l1) in an updatePanel that gets populated on changing a drop-down which is in the updatepannel as well.  I have another listbox(l2) in the updatepanel which can populate l1 via javascript.  I have 2 two items in dropdown.  Item 1 has 6 items releated to it and Item 2 has none.  When the page loads Item 1 is selected in the drop down by default and its releated data(the 6 items) are loaded into l1.  When I select Item2 in the dropdown, l2 is empty since there is no data related Item 2.  When I click save on the page, l1.Items.count() = 6 and the save routine save the 6 items releated to Item 1 to Item 2.  If I update the l1 from l2 via the client side script everything save correctly.  I'm sure if this is happening due to the updatepanel or if this just a problem with the listbox.  Do you know what is causing this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused by your update panel.

It may the

updatemode

You might need to set up a custom trigger for your update panel.

Good luck!